# Make 'dom-if' check the condition against a property in another element?

Tags: javascript, polymer-1.0

I have some code that looks like this:

```
..
<template is="dom-if" if="_myMethod()">
   <div>Hello world</div>
</template>
..
```

`_myMethod` looks like this:

```
_myMethod: function(){
   return this.$.someOtherObject.someList.size() == 0;
}
```

As you can see the method return a value from some other `polymer-element` in the page. But how do I get the `dom-if` to change it's "state" when my *other* `polymer-element` changes?

I know that if I pass a value to the method, like this: `_myMethod(someValue)` if `someValue` changes it will update the `dom-if`, but I need to "observe" a change in another `polymer-element`. How do I do what I wanna do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some experimentation I ended up with the following:

```
..
<my-other-element on-some-list-changed="_notifyChange" id="someOtherObject">
</my-other-element>
..
..
<template is="dom-if" if="_myMethod(didChange)">
   <div>Hello world</div>
</template>
..
..
_notifyDidChange: function()
{
   this.didChange = !this.didChange;
}
_myMethod: function(didChange){
   return this.$.someOtherObject.someList.size() == 0;
}
```

The `dom-if` will now update if the value (array) on the other element changes. Not sure if there's a bug (with arrays), but I tried binding to `someOtherObject.someList` directly and sync changes between the two elements, they synced, but events weren't triggered properly and thus the `dom-if` wouldn't update. :(